# how to handle react-color input should not allow more than 6 digits for hex values?

Tags: reactjs, react-color

In the given image you can see that I'm able to add more than six hexadecimal values in the Input field, how to avoid that!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXyZz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler on the inputs `onChange` and slice the input string to only be 6 characters long.

```
const [color, setColor] = useState("");

function txtColorChange(e) {
    setColor(e.target.value.slice(0,6));
}

...

<input value={color} onChange={(e)=> txtColorChange(e)}/>
```

Comment: on Doing this it not working and react-color handles change on every change of three digits so slice 0 to 6 will break the code 
```
onChange= { (e: any) => {setColor(e.target.value.length<=3 ? e.target.value.slice(0,2) : e.target.value.slice(0,5) ) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an alpha channel to edit color opacity.

The react-color's documentation said that

> "color accepts either a string of a hex color '#333' or a object of rgb or hsl values [...] Both rgb and hsl will also take a a: 1 value for alpha"

So instead of this:

```
color = {
    hex: '#f3f3f3',
}
```

You need to use an object like this:

```
color = {
    rgb: {
        r: 243,
        g: 243,
        b: 243,
        a: 1, //the opacity value is here
    },
}
```

Pay attention to convert red-blue-green hexadecimal values to decimal, on the example above the f3 become 243.